# What does `TASK_REPORT_MAX` from the `sched.h` serve for on Linux?

Tags: linux, perf

I am using the `perf trace -bla-bla-bla -e sched:sched_switch` on a `5.15.53` kernel, however looks like it is not configured to populate all the trace fields.

[trace/events/sched.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.53/source/include/trace/events/sched.h#L252) does publish the `prev_state=%s%s`, nevertheless I can not get why exactly does the `TASK_REPORT_MAX - 1` exist there? [This macro](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.53/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1618) has no docs on it, nor it is clear for me from the source code what great purpose it serves.

`perf trace ...` output shows something like:

> ```
>  0.000 Timer/19125 sched:sched_switch(prev_comm: "Timer", prev_pid: 19125 (Timer), prev_prio: 120, prev_state: 1, next_comm: "swapper/2", next_prio: 120)
> ```

Note: `prev_state: 1`. `1` is definitely not what I would expect to see there based on the link above I've sent. Do I deal with a misconfigured kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the defined bit values for task->state: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.53/source/include/linux/sched.h#L83

Among them, only the lower 8 bits are "public" (meaningful for userspace). `TASK_REPORT_MAX - 1` mask is used to keep only these bits.

`prev_state: 1` means `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE`